# Outputting Array of objects - all come on one line

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to list one property of an object for each element in an array. It is fine, but they all show up on one line.  I read to use $OFS to set the separation characters, but that didn't work either:

```
$filearray =@()
foreach($file in $files)
{
    # There is more logic here to determine what files are included
    $filearray = $filearray + $file  
}
$OFS = "`r`n"
$filearray | Select Fullname
```

Comment: what kind of objects are they? FileInfo objects from `Get-ChildItem` (dir)? `$filearray += $file` should fill an array. it will appear as seperate lines when you pipe through `select fullname`.

Comment: FYI the way to use $OFS is set it to CRLF like you have then evaluate an array variable in a double quoted string like so `"$filearray"`.  If it is still show up on one line then check the type of $filearray as @mjolinor suggests in his comments on his answer.

Comment: You've got it Keith.  If I use "$array.Fullname" it does use the $OFS.  Thanks

Comment: @user1921849 I've created an answer based on my comment above.  You can mark it as the answer if you'd like.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

The way to use $OFS is set it to CRLF like you have then evaluate an array variable in a double quoted string like so "$filearray". If it is still show up on one line then check the type of $filearray as @mjolinor suggests in his comments on his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
Foreach($file in $FileCollection)
{
 #Logic
  if($file #meets condition)
  {
    $filearray = $filearray + $file.Property
  }

}
```

That will load the array with the property value, if you know the name.

Comment: Yes, but if I need to access other properties, which I think I might need to, I can't.

Comment: Okay, so I had you add the property - just add the entire object like your code does originally. If you need to access these properties you can simply list them out like this `$FileArray|Foreach{$_.Property}`

Comment: That still displays them all on one line.

Comment: How about....
"$Filearray|%{"$_.Fullname"+ "`r`n"}"

If you cant tell, because of stackoverflow.com's formatting, there is a Grave accent before r and before n, no space between them.

Comment: This just occurred to me, can you post some of your output? perhaps there is something about the output we can identify as a pattern and split on.

Comment: Still all on one line. Even if I put "X" in the second quotes, it doesn't add X to the output.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this:

```
$filecollection | where-object  { #condition } | select FullName
```

Comment: When I say additional processing, it is significant. Not just a condition on the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'd explicitly cast $filearray to make sure it's not getting reset somewhere else in the code:

```
[array]$filearray = @()
```

Comment: If you do a gettype() on it, is it still an array?  If not then something in the unposted code is changing it.

Comment: It says Basetype = System.Array

Comment: What does $filearray | select -expand fullname get you?

Answer (score 0):

Try to force type at this line:

```
[object[]]$filearray = $filearray + $file
```

or better

```
[object[]]$filearray += $file
```

If you know the rigth type ( `[fileinfo[]]` maybe? ) you can be more accurate forcing the rigth type array